# Display an image in Java EE

Tags: image, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I'd like to retrieve and display an image in a Java EE application using JSF 2 but **WITHOUT** **using any servlet.**

I already retrieved the date from the database as Byte [] but I don't know how I'm gonna display the image in the JSF page. I tried the type `DefaultStreamedContent` and `Byte[]` without success.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? The title does not tell anything. What have you accomplished until now? Post some code to show where you need help. This question right now is a great candidate to be closed as being too broad. Please, try adjusting it.

Comment: done! I hope it's more expressive this way!

Comment: as Piotr sayd... you should post a little bit of code so we can reproduce your problem/situation... do you use only JSF or any 3rd party library like prime faces? how does your backing bean looks like? and your facelet page? why not using a simple servlet? concrete reason?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not 100% clear what you're exactly doing, the OmniFaces `graphicImage` component was indeed build to display images from `Byte[]` without using a Servlet.

For example:

Backing bean:

```
 @Named
 @ApplicationScoped
 public class ImageStreamer {

     @Inject
     private ImageService service;

     public byte[] getById(Long id) {
         return service.getContent(id);
     }
```

}

Page:

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{imageStreamer.getById(1)}" />
```

Note that this is a shortened example, and in practice you wouldn't put the hardcoded `1` there.

For a more complete example see: [showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage)